# Javascript won't output to HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, output

I am using Flask to get python lists into HTML. To iterate through the lists and print every elements, I use Javascript.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function show_tests(test, desc) {
   text = "";
   for (i = 0; i < len(desc); i++) {
      text += "<tr><td>" + test[i] + "</td><td>" + desc[i] + "</td></tr>";
   }
   return text;
 }
 </script>
```

And the call is

```
  <tbody>
  <script type="text/javascript">document.write(show_tests({{ tests }}, {{ descriptions }}));</script>
  </tbody>
```

When I run Flask and open the HTML, the data from JS dosen't show up. Anyone has any idea on why that is? 
**BTW: desc and test ALWAYS have same length.

Any help is appreciated!!

EDIT: anyone else having this problem: use jinja! I just learned about it and it's great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to be using JS here at all. There is nothing interactive here, you should do it directly in Jinja2.

view:

```
...
return render_template('mytemplate.html', zipped_tests=zip(tests, descriptions))
```

template:

```
<tbody>
    {% for test, desc in zipped_tests %}
    <tr><td>{{ test }}</td><td>{{ desc }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```